Layperson's interpretation of Marxism, communism, socialism
Disclaimer: I have distributed this across multiple Reddit subs but no valid counter-arguments.
TL;DR I haven't read Marx, the communist manifesto, or Marxist dogma-fueled commie guidebooks. But I have read intensively (at least I recognize as such) about the history of socialism, communism, Marxism, neo-Marxism/post-Marxism, and postmodernism. Open to critique and suggestions.

In the beginning socialism and communism were interchangeable, later communism became a more revolutionary and more radical branch of socialism, slightly before Karl Marx's era. Mark's literature might have widened the gap between the two, radicaling more socialists into communists.

Socialism and Capitalism were both proposed alternative solutions to Monarchy/Feudalism. Capitalism conquered. Socialists argue that capitalism long started in the agricultural age.

Communism is the utopian dream of a classless, stateless, moneyless society, where the governing body on people is no longer needed, maybe the historically proven greed in humans has been removed from the genes? Or environmental affluence makes wealth the evolutionarily meaningless. Many political parties in socialist countries identify as community parties, that claim to be moving toward communist utopia by different means. Communism in its truest form doesn't consider social/cultural issues.

Socialism has the most vague agreed-upon definition among the three and spans the entire political spectrum, authoritarian-libertarian scale, from national socialism to anarcho-socialism. Socialism is the coerced redistribution of wealth, production, or success by a governing body with the intention of making everyone equal, economically or even socially. Hence it makes libertarian socialism and anarcho-socialism kind of oxymorons because socialism in its fullest form inevitably requires authoritarian force. Many of those justify authoritarian force stating it is necessary to undo the wrong-doings of non-socialists in the past but it will slowly die away with the state. Socialism from the start also integrates social/cultural aspects of the world. But not more than a decade before Marx, socialism was dominant only in its economic sector. Later social and cultural considerations are again integrated by national socialists, neo-socialist/neo-Marxists/cultural Marxists.

Marxism is Marx's interpretation of the need for socialism/communism and the overthrow of the elite by the working class leading to communist utopia. Marxism differs from socialism in that in Marxism revolution/overthrow is necessary to achieve communism whereas socialism accepts broader approaches to communism such as democratic socialism. Marxism can said to be a part of socialism. Marxism ultimately requires vanguard. Karl Marx used to believe that overthrow by the working class could be done just by indoctrination, but later in his life, Marx changed his stance and called for a necessary pro-revolution elite guiding the working class, which renders libertarian Marxism meaningless, unless libertarian Marxism is interpreted as libertarian socialism. Marxism doesn't consider social/cultural aspects.

A socialist market economy is the combination of state-owned businesses along with private-owned businesses. Chinese socialist economists have claimed that it is too early for China to go all-in for communism because of the lack of abundance, so they considered integrating capitalism's free-market businesses into socialism and the majority of China's economic success comes from the free-market economy.

Neo-Marxism is the reintegration of social/cultural issues along with economic issues into Marxism, with the theme being the so-called oppressor and oppressed groups are defined and Marxists try to lead the revolution by the socially oppressed group (instead of working class alone). The reason stated by neo-Marxists is that not enough revolutionary energy is found in the working class after the failures of previous revolutions, hence they seek energy from other different sources. It is literally the same as cultural Marxism (Note: Wikipedia would say cultural Marxism is antisemitic and such but will put a link to the Marxist critique of culture above the page). Some might argue that neo-Marxism is the same as post-Marxism. Post-Marxism rejects Marx's narrative about the elite and working class.

Postmodernism is the stance that states there are no objective truths, and everything is up to interpretation which sets the dominant truth via power dynamics between groups. The majority of postmodernists were former Marxists and though they may not self-identify, they believe in the overthrow of the dominant narrative by the oppressed group. Postmodernists reject reason and consistency and put more emphasis on social/cultural interpretations of truth. Hence, postmodern neo-Marxist is a real thing.

Democratic socialism is the arrival of or practice of socialism/communism via democratic means, unlike revolutionary means. Socialist democracy is the practice of democracy to decide other important aspects where socialist values are protected by authority possibly in the constitution. Social democracy is the political and economic framework that integrates some level of socialist politics into the dominant capitalist economy.



More in terms of origins or roots than philosophical concepts is this. Rather biased! But still insightful as to the psychological and developmental origins of these ideologies

Hmmm… Well, all I can say is that you probably should have read something written by Marx or a Marxian theorist before posting this. This is broadly distorted and occasionally perplexing. If you're offering it as an understanding it doesn't work, in too many ways to easily correct. If you're asking a specific question I can't figure out what that question is. This isn't really the place to argue — it's a Q&A site — but if you look over some of the other questions on Marx here you should be able to piece together a more robust understanding.

Welcome! Unfortunately, PhilSE doesn't allow "What do you think?" questions. We strive more for a short, fact-based Q&A format. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help

@JD I understand a lot of StackExchange subdomains follow that routine. But what a terrible idea for a philosophy sub! Prepare to be taken over by chat bots for philosophy discussions, what could I expect less?

@HanMoeHtet Well, in practice, a certain tension and tolerance is accommodated. Area51 provides you with an opportunity to bring a more lively form of philosophy into existence. I suspect a motivated individual could bring another forum into existence. Be the change you desire to see in the world.


Yes they were used interchangeably for utopian ideas how to construct a more free and equal society with regards to economic inequality. Though there were lots of people having lots of ideas and Marx was just one of them. And not really all this extreme. He mostly analyzed the conditions of the time and beefed with people not agreeing with him. So he provided an ideological underpinning that was more rigid than most, not much utopian world building and he got involved with organizations such as the international (workingmen's association) which he lead until people were sick of him.


1.1 So at some point he was somewhat of a spokesperson of the most active movement, in that direction and popularized the ideas. Sometimes to his own dismay because his name was used synonymous with the movement though often pushing for vastly different goals than what he proposed. 2. No neither of the two was "proposed" to overcome feudalism. According to Marx capitalism already did. Solved some problems created some new and communism was envisioned to be the successor to capitalism. So he encouraged liberal revolutions and capitalism in places of feudalism and thought of them as necessary.


It essentially just means that the economic production should be cooperative where people collectively and democratically decide how to share workload and output and how to invest it. Rather than having rich people decide who gets to work for them and how they spend the value generated by that. The industrial production made it seem like work by the hour was replacing skilled labor so the mode of production would already level economic discrepancies beyond artificial inequality. So just take the power and what people do with democracy (not a thing back than) was supposed to be their thing.



Nope, redistribution or collectivization of the means of production. So in simple terms if someone owns all the land, then he can make rules for people to walk on it, hence if people want to be free from that kind of rule, they need to take control of those means of production. Also "the government" is missing the point, the people are supposed to be the government and as such are supposed to make the government (president, king, chairman, etc) superfluous and replace it with something more resembling their individual and collective needs (democracy).



No Marxism requires a capitalist mode of production which creates capitalists and proletariat as well as increased production to live of without the need for subjugation, exploitation or starvation of either part of society. So a feudal revolt would create new kings but it wouldn't change how things are produced. The Vanguard party stuff is largely Lenin's brain child following Blanc more than Marx.



Socialism as "intermediary state between capitalism and communism" is also a Leninist or even Stalinist idea to justify the discrepancy between what is supposed to happen and what is actually happening. Whether Marx's analysis and prescribed solutions were good is a different question.

